# Angular (4.1.3) ng-select2 Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I installed [ng-select2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2). And I'm getting this error and code is not able to complie after 'ng serve'.

- node version is 8.10.0
- npm version 6.0.0
- List item

OS Windows 7

`ERROR in d:/PATH-TO-PROJECT-FOLDER/node_modules/@types/select2/index.d.ts (233,49): 'JQuery' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

`ERROR in D:/PATH-TO-PROJECT-FOLDER/node_modules/ng-select2/ng-select2/ng-select2.component.ts (188,18): Cannot find name 'Select2Options'.`

`ERROR in /src/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts (91,19): Cannot find name 'Select2Options'.`

```
// Dashboard component ts(91, 19) error + I've also added import to it:
public options: Select2Options;
```

Solutions I tried are:

- As per documentation, added import and also imported in @NgModule to app.module.ts
- I've jquery@3.2.1 and @types/jquery@2.0.41 installed as well.
- npm cache verify, then npm cache clean --force and updated npm
- deleted package-lock.json and then ran npm install
  But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the github issue: 
The interface Select2Options is removed/renamed to Options in the latest version 4.0.45

To resolve this issue, I simply downgrade the package to 4.0.44 by running
npm install @ types/select2@4.0.44 --save and this worked for me.

https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/issues/124

Comment: I've not that reputation. It has to be above 15, I think!

Answer (score 0):

**I had a similar problem. I installed according to the selected2 documentation. Unfortunately, an error appeared**

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:6:33 - error TS2307: **Cannot find module './select2**' or its corresponding type declarations.
6 import { NgSelect2Module } from './select2';

**Although it was in the Initial Chunk Files**

```
Initial Chunk Files               | Names      
select2.js                        | select2
```

**I tried your solution but the compiler said it is not a module.**

Error: src/app/app.module.ts:6:33 - error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/admin/Documents/WorkspaceAngular/medical-v0.9/node_modules/@types/select2/index.d.ts' **is not a module**.

6 import { NgSelect2Module } from '@types/select2',

**So I installed componenet**
npm i ng-select2-component --save

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2-component

**It worked ;-)**